# decompress zlib with boost library

Tags: c++, boost, zlib

I'm working with XMPP protocol which is zlib compressed, I want to know how to decompress(and compress) its zlib data with boost library. The zlib data is ended with "00 00 FF FF", I googled it and found some keyword about sync/flush. There is a line in boost's zlib.hpp:

```
BOOST_IOSTREAMS_DECL extern const int sync_flush;
```

But I can't find any document about using it.

The sample packets captured from a third-part program:
[image: XMPP packet with zlib encryption]

I guess packet *38* and *39*, totally 275 bytes contain all the zlib data, because packet 41 is server response, is it correct?

Here's my code to decompress the above packet, but it crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

std::string zlib_decompress(const std::string& data) {
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;

    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input>in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(boost::make_iterator_range(data));
    std::string decompressed;
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, boost::iostreams::back_inserter(decompressed));
    return decompressed;
}

int main() {
    // the 275 bytes data 
    string s("\x78\x9c\x2c\x8b\x41\x0a\xc0\x20\x0c\xc0\xbe\x22\x7d\x80\x6e\x57\x99\xfb\x8b\x4a\x99\x0e\xb5\xa3\x2d\xc3\xe7\xef\xe0\x4e\x81\x90\x1c\xa2\x8c\xb1\xfb\x05\xa3\x14\x00\xa3\x60\xa7\x64\x33\x75\x30\xb3\xb7\x21\x01\xee\x98\x12\xb2\xcf\xad\xe2\xd0\xdf\xfe\x4f\x80\xa2\xfa\x78\xe7\x50\x0b\xf2\xb4\x2b\xb5\xc4\x97\x5b\x81\x80\x79\x91\xa5\xd2\x08\xb0\xdb\x0d\xce\x0f\x00\x00\xff\xff\x3c\x8f\xc9\x0a\xc2\x30\x18\x84\x5f\x45\xbc\x8b\x5d\x14\xa4\x54\x21\xa5\x41\x03\xfe\xa9\x95\x88\xe8\x2d\x8d\x95\x9a\x2e\x84\x2e\x36\xcd\xd3\x9b\x5e\x3c\x7c\x0c\x0c\xcc\x0c\x13\xf2\xa1\x2f\x16\x75\x2e\x0a\xde\x7c\x3a\x5b\x70\x39\x23\x42\xff\x5b\x43\xdb\x04\x9f\xbc\x7f\x07\x8a\xb7\x36\x1d\x58\x3b\x68\x66\x51\x6a\xd5\xf1\xae\x5a\x1e\x84\xaf\xfa\xcc\x73\x0b\xe2\x47\x9d\x38\xa9\x37\x48\xa4\x29\xc3\x1a\x64\x39\x81\x21\xda\x32\x52\xf9\x74\x5e\x06\x0c\x8d\x1f\x4e\x82\x22\x93\xd7\xee\x37\xbb\x63\x29\x8e\x7a\xcc\xab\xdd\x04\x31\x76\x81\xe1\x29\x61\xc4\x80\xc4\x16\xe4\xd1\xe6\xea\x83\x01\x87\xca\x74\x83\x62\x32\x02\xbb\x69\x60\x64\x0b\x12\x26\x60\x33\xc2\x7d\x9d\x84\x6d\x4d\x3d\x1a\x97\xfb\x70\x3d\x3f\x39\xfc\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff", 275);
    cout << zlib_decompress(s) << endl; // it crashes
}
```

Comment: That means that you are getting a partial zlib stream. You haven't said what happens you try to decompress it.

Comment: @MarkAdler. The code crashes, I tried to debug the code but failed to understand the code of boost zlib. I've updated the post with more info.